# Finding a comparable Control group for a treatment group?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics

I have a treatment group of size 30 (30 schools in California) that used a math supplemental software. In a simple analysis, I'd like to compare students' average Math growth between our treatment group and a comparable control group. There are many schools in CA that didn't use the software. I'd like the control group to include similar performing schools (their baseline scores be similar to treatment schools with a reasonable margin of error). Also, I'd like the control group sample size be 3 times of my treatment (here 90 schools). There are many many choices of 90 schools out of more than 1000 schools in CA. How would you choose your control group?

Comment: You may say the more information, the better. Use all CA schools and fit an ANCOVA (assuming that the distribution of control and treatment have overlap). I agree, it's good. However, I'd like to show that both group had a very similar average baseline score and variance of scores in the baseline which is not possible if we consider the whole CA specially that the treatment group are more low-performing schools.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds unhelpful, but I've voted to close this question.  As it's written, there doesn't figure to be any one correct answer, and I'm not sure the question's about statistics.  The best response might well be "read everything you can on research design."  But if your intention was to solicit opinions about some specific aspect you have in mind about a design for this situation, please focus in on that--it should make for a more productive Q+A.

Comment: The only comment that I would like to mention is generally when you have a highly imbalanced design like 3:1 in your case the estimation of mean difference is inefficient. In one example where I did something like this for a test on the mean difference a 1:1 randomization required 50 patients in each group (100 in total) whereas a 3:1 randomization required 99 in the treatment group and 33 in the control for a total of 132. The same problem could occur for you even though the ratio treatment to control is 1:3.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Would you please elaborate more that why the estimate is in-efficient? Obviously, I cannot change the sample size in treatment group, but for control group, I can get more information by increasing the sample size and therefore, I can gain more efficiency for the estimated growth in control group.

Comment: @rolando2 : thank you for your answer. I'm fairly new to Cross Validated. I was thinking that I could contribute to it. I started contributing to Stackoverflow 2 days ago, and although I did spend a little time, but I got reputation of 113. My first experience was a little disappointing that someone voted me -1 and you think we should close the question. I'm a statistician and have worked in this area for the previous 3 years and based on my experience working with real world data, I think it's an important question.

Comment: I would download the [California API results][1] for the relevant years and use them as a source of data about the schools and their academic performance.  They have roughly 150 fields pertaining to the school and [demographics][2] of the student body as well as the API test results themselves.  You should have little trouble picking out a control group based on what you believe to be relevant characteristics of the test group.

  [1]: http://www.cde.ca.gov/ta/ac/ap/apidatafiles.asp
  [2]: http://www.cde.ca.gov/ta/ac/ap/reclayout11b.asp

Comment: @jbowman: Thank you. I'm aware of the website. By writing this question, I meant to ask a general question that how people think of finding a comparable control group. Suppose that we have a potentially 300 comparable schools, how you would choose 90 of them for your analysis?

Comment: @Sepehr I disagree with roland2 about the appropriateness of your question here.  I think it relates to experimental desing is sues and hence is appropriate for CV.  Regarding the efficiency issue that I brought up my implicit assumption is that the two populations have the same variances (or at least the variances are close to being equal).  In that case an estimate of mean difference based on a fixed total sample size n will less accurate when the sample sizes are unequal and it gets worse as the imbalance increases.

Comment: So in my example in a 3:1 randomization it takes a larger total sample size (132 compared to 100) to achieve the same accuracy or power for a test.

Comment: (+1) @Michael (and everyone else): The clearest and most effective way to express your agreement that the question is appropriate here is to **vote it up**.  Sepehr, welcome to our site!

Comment: @MichaelChernick: Exactly. This is the challenge that we have. By using more control schools, we gain efficiency in terms of estimating the growth in students' math scores in control group but on the other hand, since we have more comparable schools to treatment group, the control group obviously has smaller variance ==> the constant variance assumption is violated. So, instead of comparing them using t-test with constant variance, we should compare them using t-test without any assumption on equality of variances. Since we have a big variance, the t-test has big degress of freedom...

Comment: So, since we have big DF, although we loose some DF for not having the equal variance assumption, but that would be matter that much.

Comment: I gave it an upvote @Sepehr. Since the variances are very different unbalanced samples are actually more efficient than balanced ones would be.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: Thank you. This post has shown the potential to become a featured post LOL

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to find optimal balance in covariates between your control and treatment group. If that's so I'd use a matching procedure.

R package *Matching* has all the functions needed for this, including some tools to assess if balance between groups has been achieved after the matching. Check [this paper](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/papers/MatchingJSS.pdf) with details about its use and some examples.